# How can I have tox test against all available versions of dependencies?

Tags: tox

I've inherited a python program where the previous author pinned all their dependencies at ancient versions and left them that way. I want to update them. I tried testing against the current versions and (unsurprisingly) they break.

I want to find the most recent dependency versions that worked. Tox.ini has ways to generate environments from a pattern, e.g. `envlist = py27-dependency{1,2}` and then specify dep versions based on the pattern. But all the examples require specifying an explicit list, and an exhaustive list of versions would be...non-optimal.

I would like to generate an env for all available versions of each dependency between the old pinned version and the current version; and have tox tell me which combinations pass tests. Is this possible?

Comment: This is probably a long shot, but did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't. I ended up using an explicit list with an entry for each minor version.

Comment: If you ever have your effort public e.g. in a commit, I'd love to see it (and maybe future readers too)